# What is the best way to get a dump of unique partition keys from Cassandra from a large column family?

Tags: cassandra

```
create table t(
key string,
time timeuuid,
val string
) primary key (key,time)
```

I found 2 methods.

1 - use COPY. But when using COPY I am getting multiple lines for combination of key,time. I just want unique row keys.

2 - Through code using select *.

Above methods are also slower.
Is there a better and faster way to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get distinct partition keys from C\* table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454716/get-distinct-partition-keys-from-c-table)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT key FROM t` should do the trick

Comment: I will not recommend Capture as mentioned in the duplicate marked answer . My 2 nodes went OOM when I tried that.

Answer (score 0):

use the sstablekeys utility to dump the keys from the Cassandra table. Here is the reference

[sstablekeys utility](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsSSTableKeys.html)